# What's the best way to achieve parameterized "on tap"/"on click" behavior for a list row?

Tags: swiftui

So let's say I have a list component in SwiftUI:

```
struct MyListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(...) { rec in
            Row(rec)
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say I want to make this reusable, and I want the "caller" of this view to determine what happens when I tap on each row view.  What would be the correct way to insert that behavior?

Comment: by `the "caller" of this view` you mean the view contains that view, right ? Otherwise i don't know what you meant

Comment: Yes exactly, the view which contains this view

Comment: in that case, i've update my answer, please check if it's what you need

Comment: Hmm I think not quite: so what I'm missing here is for CallerView to be able to trigger either a navigation link, or a sheet of some arbitrary action right?  It seems like that's still inside the list.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, could you edit your question with more detail like what output you expect for specific input ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some other Buttons in ListView example that you can run and play with it yourself

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestTableView: View {
    @State private var item: MyItem?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                // Cell as Button that display Sheet
                ForEach(1...3, id:\.self) { i in
                    Button(action: { item = MyItem(number: i) }) {
                        TestTableViewCell(number: i)
                    }
                }
                
                // Cell as NavigationLink
                ForEach(4...6, id:\.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TestTableViewCell(number: i)) {
                        TestTableViewCell(number: i)
                    }
                }
                
                // If you want a button inside cell which doesn't trigger the whole cell when being touched
                HStack {
                    TestTableViewCell(number: 7)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: { item = MyItem(number: 7) }) {
                        Text("Button").foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
            }
        }.sheet(item: $item) { myItem in
            TestTableViewCell(number: myItem.number)
        }
    }
    
    struct MyItem: Identifiable {
        var number: Int
        var id: Int { number }
    }
}

struct TestTableViewCell: View {
    var number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("View Number \(number)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to for instance show a sheet or push to a navigation link from a button action?

Comment: sure is. I've updated my answer that includes both navigation link and sheet initiator

Answer (score 0):

Make it like Button and takes an action param that is a closure.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you're looking for a reusable generic List view with tap on delete functionality. If I'm guessing right my approach then would be like this:

```
struct MyArray: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var myArray = [
        MyArray(title: "One"),
        MyArray(title: "Two"),
        MyArray(title: "Three"),
        MyArray(title: "Four"),
        MyArray(title: "Five"),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        MyListView(array: myArray) { item in
            Text(item.title)  // row view
        } onDelete: { item in
            myArray.removeAll(where: {$0.id == item.id}) // delete func
        }
    }
}


struct MyListView<Items, Label>: View 
where Items: RandomAccessCollection, Items.Element: Identifiable, Label: View {
    
    var array: Items
    var row: (Items.Element) -> Label
    var onDelete: (Items.Element) -> ()
    
    var body : some View {
        List(array) { item in
            Button {
                onDelete(item)
            } label: {
                row(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```